# Cannot boot on Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, system-installation

I just installed Ubuntu on my Acer Aspire X3995 (if it is relevant) following the steps described [there](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) and [there](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop). For my Windows, **which I want to conserve**, there are already two small reserved partitions and a bigger one where the OS is installed.

I created a fourth partition using the remaining space. Note that I had to do this because the installer did not propose me to install Ubuntu alongside with Windows, saying that no OS was found, that's why I chose the last manual option. I chose sda4 to install Linux on , st4, /. I also chose this partition as the one where the root program were to be installed. After the completion of the installation, I rebooted but it automically booted on Windows, so I rebooted on Linux thanks to the USB device.

I ran some commands after rebooting :

```
sudo mount /dev/sdax /mnt 
sudo fdisk -l
```

adivced by a friend of mine, that seem to confirm Linux is well installed on sta4 ; here is the output :

[image]

I tried many things and researched a lot about Secure Boot, UFI and so on but nothing worked (most of the time I could not follow the steps because I don't have the expected options in my menu). Any idea of how I could finally (dual-)boot on Linux without a USB device ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved my problem. Here are the steps I followed :

- reboot on USB, choose "Try Ubuntu without installing"
- install and launch [Boot repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)
- as the first attempt failed, I relaunched the tool without rebooting
- reboot without USB. The PC booted directly on Ubuntu (which was still not what I wanted)
- `sudo os-prober` shown me that Windows 7 was still detected
- execute `sudo update-grub`
- reboot : that's ok !